# If $\sin A = 4/5$ with $A$ in QII, find $\cos A/2$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification

For the following, assume that all the given angles are in simplest form, so that if A is in QIV you may assume that 270° < A < 360°.

If $\sin A = 4/5$ with A in QII, find $\cos A/2$

I keep getting $\cos \frac A2=-\frac{\sqrt5}5$, which I think is incorrect.

Comment: You will have a 3-4-5 triangle in QII, so the value of $ \cos A \ $ is?  Then, half of an angle in QII will mean $ \ \frac{A}{2} \ $ is in QI.

Answer (score 2):

Cos(A/2) = sqrt((1+cosA)/2)

= sqrt(1-(3/5)/2)

= sqrt(1/5)

= 1/(sqrt(5))

= ( sqrt(5))/5

Comment: The half-angle is in the _first_ quadrant...

Comment: It's late... ;)

Comment: Wait so will every half angle be in the previous quadrant or no?

Comment: Consider the angle intervals represented by the quadrants:  QI -- $ (0, \frac{\pi}{2}) $   ,   QII -- $ (\frac{\pi}{2} , \pi) $   ,  QIII -- $ (\pi , \frac{3 \pi}{2}) $   ,  QIV -- $ (\frac{3 \pi}{2} , 2 \pi) \ $ .  The half-angles would fall into QI, QI, QII, and QII.